# Jest validation error: module ts-jest in the transform option was not found

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, spfx, ts-jest

I am using jest for SPFx project testing. It was working fine but since I have upgraded jest from 24* to 27*, I am getting below error.

```
Validation error
 Module ts-jest in the transform option was not found
```

My jest.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
     preset: '@voitanos/jest-preset-spfx-react16',
     testMatch: ['**/*.test.+(js|ts|tsx)'],
     rootDir: '../src',
     setFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/../../../config/jest.setup.js'],
     globals: {
       CYPRESS: false,
       'test-jest': {
          diagnos: false
       }
     }
}
```